# How can I get leaf node from ANTLR4 tree

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I tried ANTLR4 methods but I am getting the tree or text along with the Terminal Node. Which is fine.

But I want to get extracted value (or leaf Node) that shows in figure.(FRAME-1-PROGRAM)
Please share your valuable ideas for helping me. Please let me know how can I get that value.[image]

Comment: Can you share your grammar? (or the relevant parts / minimal working example)?

Comment: Also a bit of Java code could help to contextualize the problem. e.g.: is this "extraction" supposed to happen in a visitor or elsewhere?